# Tutorials on complex analysis

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, reference-request

Where can I find some good tutorials (notebook files) about complex analysis theory & applications using Mathematica? Currently I can only find a book by [Shaw](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316036549).

Comment: Other than google search, if you go to [www.wolfram.com/books](http://www.wolfram.com/books/search.html) and in the search box, type `complex analysis` then some books come up on the topic. (other than the Shaw book).

Comment: Google Fu: "wolfram mathematica complex analysis"

Comment: Try http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8104/

Comment: Thanks for your support!    @Bill Watts, these nb files are not input files, just script  which I can only read...

Comment: Download and unzip the zip file and you get a bunch of executable nb files, not script files.  You need to open the subgroups.

Comment: @BillWatts , e.g. in Chapter01Section01.nb,  I can only see the text/equation, but no codes which I can study to use in mathematica

Comment: Each place it says Exploration, is a closed subgroup.  You can open each one separately, or use ctrl-A to select the entire notebook, then go to the top menu to cell-grouping-open all subgroups, and you will see all the code under Exploration topic.

Comment: @BillWatts, thanks very much, I have found it!!

Comment: My problem is solved! e.g. see the answers by @BillWatts.

Comment: Good thread!! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure that the answer from comments is retained:

[Bill Watts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53121/bill-watts) suggested the following resource [in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173060/tutorials-on-complex-analysis#comment454379_173060):

> [Complex Analysis: Mathematica Notebooks](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8104/)

This item contains complex analysis software coded in Mathematica 8.0. The examples are described in the textbook *Complex Analysis: for Mathematics and Engineering* by [John H. Mathews](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/) and Russell Howell (6th Edition, Jones & Bartlett, Pub. Inc., Burlington, MA, 2011).

Answer (score 1):

You'll find some notebooks about complex analysis, and especially about visualizing complex functions, on my web page:

http://blogs.umass.edu/math421-murray/files/

*Disclaimer"* These notebooks are several years old now and not guaranteed to work with current versions of Mathematica; moreover, many use David Park's add-on application *Presentations*`. (Gradually I'm revising those notebooks and will post updates when available. If you wish, contact me directly at the email on the cited website.)